# Memoising based on a key

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I've been playing around with the MemoCombinators and MemoTrie packages lately and I was trying to memoise a function which was taking a tree (which was really a DAG in disguise as several of the nodes were shared). In the form of:

```
data Tree k a = Branch (Tree k a) (k, a) (Tree k a) | Leaf (k, a)
```

So I want to memoise a function of type (based on it's key):

```
Tree k a -> b
```

Now I have a vague understanding that these memoisation combinators are used to turn your function `f :: a -> a` into a structure of lazy (unevaluated) values of `a`, so that when you pull one out it is already evaluated. So that wouldn't be a problem with my Tree - somehow I'd need turn it into a structure of values indexed by `k`.

I couldn't figure out how to do it with the combinator libraries. One easy way around it is to make a function `k -> a` which indexes a map, which fits in just fine but that seems a little clunky.

Am I misguided in this goal, or have I missed something obvious?

I can easily see how to write this function out with this kind of style, explicitly threading my "table" through all the computations:

```
f :: Tree Int Int -> Map Int Int -> (Int, Map Int Int)
f (Branch l (k, x) r) m | (Just r) <- lookup k m = r
                        | otherwise = (max rl rr, m'')
     where 
       (rl, m') = (f l m) 
       (rr, m'') = (f r m')
```

But that is not so nice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, most memoization techniques use state.  The memoized version of a function
keeps a collection mapping inputs to memoized outputs.  When it gets an input, it checks the collection,
returning the memoized value if available.  Otherwise, it computes the output using the original
version of the function, saves the output in the collection, and returns the newly memoized output.
The memoized collection, therefore, grows over the lifespan of the function.

Haskell memoizers like the ones you mention eschew state, and instead precompute a data structure
that holds the collection of memoized outputs, using laziness to insure that the value of a particular
output isn't computed until needed.  This has a lot in common with the stateful approach, except for a few key points:

- Since the collection is immutable, it never grows.  Unmemoized outputs are recomputed each time.
- Since the collection is created before the function is used, it doesn't know
  which inputs will be used.  So the memoizer has to provide a collection of inputs over which
  to memoize.

This is fairly straightforward to implement by hand:

```
module Temp where
import Prelude hiding (lookup)
import Control.Arrow ((&&&))
import Data.Map (fromList, lookup)

data Tree k a = Branch (Tree k a) (k, a) (Tree k a) | Leaf (k, a)

key :: Tree k a -> k
key (Leaf (k, _)) = k
key (Branch _ (k,_) _) = k

-- memoize a given function over the given trees
memoFor :: Ord k => [Tree k a] -> (Tree k a -> b) -> Tree k a -> b
memoFor ts f = f'
  where f' t = maybe (f t) id $ lookup (key t) m
        m = fromList $ map (key &&& f) ts
```

What the MemoCombinators and MemoTrie packages try to do is make the collection of inputs implicit (using functions
and type-classes, repsectively).  If all the possible inputs can be enumerated, then we can
use that enumeration to build our data structure.

In your case, since you want to memoize on just the `key` of your trees, the easiest way might
be to use the `wrap` function from the MemoCombinators package:

> wrap :: (a -> b) -> (b -> a) -> Memo a -> Memo b
>
> Given a memoizer for a and an isomorphism between a and b, build a memoizer for b.

So if your `key` values have a corresponding `Memo` value (like, say, `type Key = Int`),
and you have a bijection from `Key`s to `Tree Key Val`, then you can use 
that bijection to make a memoizer for your `Tree Key Val` functions:

```
memoize :: (Tree Key Val -> b) -> (Tree Key Val -> b)
memoize = wrap keyToTree treeToKey memoForKey
```

---

**Update**: If you can't create such a mapping ahead of time, perhaps the solution is to use a state monad so you can memoize on the go:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
-- ... 

import Control.Monad.State (MonadState, gets, modify)
import Data.Map (Map, insert)
-- ... 

memoM :: (Ord k, MonadState (Map k b) m) => (Tree k a -> m b) -> (Tree k a -> m b)
memoM f = f'
  where f' t = do
        let k = key t
        v <- gets $ lookup k
        case v of
          Just b -> return b
          Nothing -> do
            b <- f t
            modify $ insert k b
            return b

-- example of use
sumM :: (Ord k, MonadState (Map k Int) m) => Tree k Int -> m Int
sumM = memoM $ \t -> case t of
        Leaf (_,b) -> return b
        Branch l (_,b) r -> do
          lsum <- sumM l
          rsum <- sumM r
          return $ lsum + b + rsum
```

Comment: See - that's the trouble. There's no easy way to write keyToTree unless I make an external map (from key -> Tree).

Comment: Looking at how you wrote memoFor - the problem is that the domain of trees is not easily found, and they can't be manufactured out of thin air. When building the table structure, be it a list or an array it needs to be a function of something which can be constructed (or is provided as a list as memoFor). Hmm.

Comment: @Oliver: Well, how would you feel about updating your code to use a monad?  Then you could use state and cache as you get stuff.  I'll update with an example.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot. I have a much more thorough understanding of the technique used by the combinators now (and why my question can't work). I couldn't make the gap why the explicit passing method worked but I couldn't get the types to line up for the automatic methods. Cheers! Oliver